# White space on the right of page after screen orientation change

Tags: ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

[Problem Demo](http://demo.xavortm.com/veetoh/1.0%20-%20Homepage.html)
The problem is visible on IOS device (tested on iPhone 5). When viewing the page in landscape mode and switching to portrait mode, white space on the right side of the page shows up.It should be connected with mobile browser that is supported by iOS devices (Safari).

I tested on Xperia V for example and this problem is not there. Do you have any suggestions on how could i fix this issue?

The template is build on bootstrap and uses owl carousel in the slider. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried **white-space: nowrap;** ??

Comment: I dont think this is the issue. As i see from people that have similar problem it is caused by bootstrap and something with the meta settings. (not that bootstrap is wrong, i think its ios fault :D)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

i had a similar issue with a kindle and this helped me out... hope is works.

Comment: That stops the user from zooming. I have added tho JS script that will handle the zoom. The issue here is because of how iOS devices usuall work with bootstrap. The solution i found for the time being is to add overflow-x: scroll to body and html. That way it just wont be possible to scroll right to see the that white area. But it is istill there and its not the best solution.

Comment: add user-scalable=yes to the end to enable the zoom and max scale 2.0

Comment: That is still not something that fixes the problem. (Thought, its not visible allready in the demo, becasue i fixed it as i said by adding overflow-x:hidden) As i said the problem is that it addes white space on the right, its not something that has to do with meta tags.